# How to get url from okhttp3.ResponseBody?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

I use Retrofit 2 in my project. I need to handle the errors of parsing and log the request URL in case of an error.

I want to do everything in one place. So I made a wrapper for parsing at the retrofit level.

Factory:

```
import okhttp3.RequestBody
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import retrofit2.Converter
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import java.lang.reflect.Type
import javax.inject.Inject

class LogGsonConverterFactory @Inject constructor(private val factory: GsonConverterFactory) : Converter.Factory() {

    override fun responseBodyConverter(
        type: Type,
        annotations: Array<out Annotation>,
        retrofit: Retrofit
    ): Converter<ResponseBody, *>? {
        val delegate: Converter<ResponseBody, *>? = factory.responseBodyConverter(type, annotations, retrofit)

        return LogResponseBodyConverter(delegate ?: return null)
    }

    override fun requestBodyConverter(
        type: Type, parameterAnnotations: Array<out Annotation>,
        methodAnnotations: Array<out Annotation>,
        retrofit: Retrofit
    ): Converter<*, RequestBody>? = factory.requestBodyConverter(type, parameterAnnotations, methodAnnotations, retrofit)
}
```

Converter:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import retrofit2.Converter

class LogResponseBodyConverter<T>(private val converter: Converter<ResponseBody, T>) : Converter<ResponseBody, T> {

    override fun convert(value: ResponseBody): T? {
        try {
            return converter.convert(value)
        } catch (parseException: JsonSyntaxException) {
            // Here I want to get URL and log an exception. But how to get url?
            throw parseException
        }
    }
}
```

Through reflection I can do it

```
((Http1ExchangeCodec.ChunkedSource) ((Exchange.ResponseBodySource) ((RealBufferedSource) ((ForwardingSource) ((RealBufferedSource) ((ResponseBody.BomAwareReader) value.reader).source).source).delegate).source).delegate).url
```

Or with an interceptor that I can provide to the parser

```
import android.util.LongSparseArray
import androidx.core.util.set
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.Response
import javax.inject.Inject

interface LastRequestSource {
    fun getLastUrl(): String?
    fun getLastCode(): Int?

    fun clearCache()
}

private const val INIT_CACHE_CAPACITY = 5

@ApplicationScope
class LastRequestInterceptorImpl @Inject constructor() : Interceptor, LastRequestSource {

    private val urlCache = LongSparseArray<String?>(INIT_CACHE_CAPACITY)
    private val codeCache = LongSparseArray<Int?>(INIT_CACHE_CAPACITY)

    override fun getLastUrl(): String? = urlCache[Thread.currentThread().id]

    override fun getLastCode(): Int? = codeCache[Thread.currentThread().id]

    override fun clearCache() {
        val threadId = Thread.currentThread().id

        urlCache.remove(threadId)
        codeCache.remove(threadId)
    }

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response =
        chain.proceed(chain.request()).also {
            synchronized(this) {
                val threadId = Thread.currentThread().id

                urlCache[threadId] = it.request.url.toString()
                codeCache[threadId] = it.code
            }
        }
}
```

Is there a more correct way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: A more general use-case could be solved with [okhttp-logging-interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor). Maybe use this an example.

Answer (score 0):

[ZoomX — Android Logger Interceptor](https://medium.com/@Iabdulgawad/zoomx-android-logging-tool-a425989e8c8c) is a great interceptor can help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object delegateObj = readField(value, "delegate");
Object sourceObj1 = readField(delegateObj, "source");
Object sourceObj2 = readField(sourceObj1, "source");
Object sourceObj3 = readField(sourceObj2, "source");
Object sourceObj4 = readField(sourceObj3, "source");
Object sourceObj5 = readField(sourceObj4, "source");
HttpUrl url = (HttpUrl) readField(sourceObj5, "url");



Object readField(Object obj, String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field f = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    f.setAccessible(true);
    return f.get(obj);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  In addition to the code you've provided, consider giving a summary as to why this solves the issue.